# Postgres Query based on Delimited String

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, csv, inner-join

we have a column in one of our tables that consist of a delimited string of ID's, like this:   72,73,313,502.

What I need to do in the query, is to parse that string, and for each ID, join it to another table.   So in the case of this string, I'd get 4 rows.......like the ID and the name from the other table.

Can this be done in a query?

Answer (score 1):

One option is `regexp_split_to_table()` and a lateral join. Assuming that the CSV string is stored in `table1(col)` and that you want to join each element against `table2(id)`, you would do:

```
select ...  -- whatever columns you want
from table1 t1
cross join lateral regexp_split_to_table(t1.col, ',') x(id)
inner join table2 t2 on t2.id = x.id::int
```

It should be noted that storing CSV strings in a relational database is bad design, and should almost always be avoided. Each value in the list should be stored as a separate row, using the proper datatype. Recommended reading: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/10676716)